# Pass additional info for event handlers while triggering change event programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

```
$('#idofElement').change(function(e, additionalData) {
  //event code
}

$('#idofElement').trigger('change', { someAdditionalData : 'value' });
```

I'm triggering a change event from code as you can see above. I want to pass some additional info to event handler. Wanted to know if something like that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by passing a variable with Jquery Trigger, and then opening up your event handler to extra variables. Here is an example:

```js
$("#foo").on("click", function(event, data1, data2) {
  console.log(data1); //logs "hello"
  console.log(data2); //logs "goodbye"
});

$('input:button').click(function() {
  $("#foo").trigger("click", ["hello", "goodbye"]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="foo" type="text" />
<input type="button" value="click me to trigger change event" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store data with data() method like that :

```
$('#idofElement').trigger('change').data('someAdditionalData', value);
```

Then you can access to data object like this :

```
$('#idofElement').on('change', function(){
    if(data = $(this).data('someAdditionnalData')) {
       data...
    }
});
```

And if you want remove object data, do

```
$('#idofElement').removeData('someAdditionnalData');
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// say your selector and click handler looks something like this...

$("some selector").click({param1: "Hello", param2: "World"}, cool_function);

// in your function, just grab the event object and go crazy...
function cool_function(event){
    alert(event.data.param1);
    alert(event.data.param2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can with `jQuery.trigger`

$(selector).trigger( "click", [ "foo", "bar" ] );